# Left join if active and exists

Tags: mysql

I have multiple tables, the first one contains a value, the other should be joined if they exist, there is a value and the `active` state is one:

```
        Table 1
+------+-------+--------+
|  id  | value | active |
+------+-------+--------+
|  1   |   v1  |    1   |
|  2   |   v2  |    1   |
|  3   |   v3  |    1   |
+------+-------+--------+

             Table 2                              Table 3             
+------+-------+-------+--------+    +------+-------+-------+--------+
|  id  | link  | value | active |    |  id  | link  | value | active |
+------+-------+-------+--------+    +------+-------+-------+--------+
|  1   |   1   |  v21  |    1   |    |  1   |   1   |  v31  |    1   |
|  2   |   2   |  v22  |    0   |    |  2   |   2   |  v32  |    1   |
|  3   |   3   |  v23  |    1   |    +------+-------+-------+--------+
+------+-------+-------+--------+
```

Now I want to have the `Table 1` to be extended to contain the values of `Table 2` and `Table 3` if there is a value and if the value is `active=1`. The resulting table should like this:

```
             Result 
+------+-------+-------+--------+
|  id  | value | tbl 2 | tbl 3  |
+------+-------+-------+--------+
|  1   |   v1  |  v21  |   v31  |  -- values exist in every table
|  2   |   v2  |  NULL |   v32  |  -- active is 0 in Table 2 -> value tbl 2 = NULL
|  3   |   v3  |  v23  |   NULL |  -- value does not exist in Table 3 -> value tbl 3 = NULL
+------+-------+-------+--------+
```

I tried the query

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
    `Table 1`.*, 
    IF(`Table 2`.`active` = 1, `Table 2`.`value`, NULL) AS tbl2, 
    IF(`Table 3`.`active` = 1, `Table 3`.`value`, NULL) AS tbl3
FROM 
    `Table 1` 
LEFT JOIN 
    `Table 2` ON `Table 1`.`id` = `Table 2`.`link`
LEFT JOIN 
    `Table 3` ON `Table 1`.`id` = `Table 3`.`link`
WHERE 
    `Table 1`.`active` = 1 
LIMIT <limit> OFFSET <offset>
```

This works and gives the expected result. But after putting in the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` it takes extremely long. My `Table 1` has over 2000 values, also I'm not just joining `Table 2` and `Table 3` but another 10 additional tables. They also have more than 2000 records.

I have an index on the `link` columns and the `Table 1.id` column.

*How can I speed up this query? Is it the fastest way?*

I am wondering because I did not expect MYSQL to have performance troubles with 2000 rows. But I'm not good in MYSQL so this might be the worst solution possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this:

```
SELECT          table1.id,
                table1.value AS tab1_value,
                table2.value AS tab2_value,
                table3.value AS tab3_value
FROM            table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
             ON table1.id = table2.link
            AND table2.value IS NOT NULL -- not strictly necessary
            AND table2.active = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3
             ON table1.id = table3.link
            AND table3.value IS NOT NULL -- not strictly necessary
            AND table3.active = 1
WHERE           table1.active = 1;
```

Comment: works perfectly, thank you very much :) I didn't think about `OUTER JOIN` but as I said I'm not too good in MYSQL. Thank you again :)

Comment: @miile7: `LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` are the same thing. I'm just old-fashioned and prefer to mention it explicitly. The difference is the fact that the 'active' flag is included in the join-criterion.

Comment: oh, thank you for pointing that out. I thought `LEFT JOIN` is equal to a `LEFT INNER JOIN` but I didn't look it up.

Comment: @miile7: `JOIN` is equal to `INNER JOIN` while `LEFT JOIN` equals `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Kinda confusing. That's why I prefer to mention it explicitely.